# copying a nested dictionary

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a dict with integer keys and the value for each key is a map with integer keys and set of integers as value.

Ex:

```
x = {
    3 : {0:set([1,2,5]), 1:set([3]), 2:set([7,8])},
    4 : {0:set([1,2]),   1:set([4]), 2:set([7])},
    }
```

I am trying to write a function that does the following operation:

Given a key(k) which is present in each value of `x` (say 2), it should return a new dict with similar structure and following properties:

- Key(T) : An element in the union of all values under `k`
- Value  : A dict with same inner keys, but the value for a given inner key(`k'`) is union of all sets associated with `k'` in old dict that have `T in x[k]`

In the above example, if the argument is `k=2` then it should return:

```
y = {
    7 : {0:set([1,2,5]), 1:set([3,4]),  2:set([7])},
    8 : {0:set([1,2,5]), 1:set([3]),    2:set([8])},
    }
```

I am currently doing this by iterating over all possible values under `k` in the old dict and constructing the new one. Is there an efficient way of doing this ?

Comment: @^ no it is not...the reason I have not provided the actual code is that the current code involves lots of unnecessary extra details of the project that I am currently involved in..

Comment: Tried to cleanup your examples (which were incorrect) -- are they correct now?

Comment: May I suggest taking your current code and positing it for review at codereview.stackexchange.com? As it stands, attempting to determine your function from your description is difficult.

Answer (score 4):

You have to create the copy of the object also for that you can use `deepcopy` of `copy` module. check http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy for detail. This will copy all object and basic data.

Comment: If you making a brand new dict object, you don't copy the old one -- you just make a new one.